# Help with set bijection proof

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $f: M \to N$ be a bijection

Let $A, B \subset M$

Then show:

1. $f(A \cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$
2. $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$

I have no idea how to do this honestly!

How do you go about doing this? Can you draw a picture to solve these types of problems? Must $f$ be a bijection?

Comment: It is always the same with these kinds of exercises. Choose an arbitrary $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then write what that means and infer (after a few steps) that $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$. Then you have proved that $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$. When you have done that, do it the other way around.

Comment: After reaching 5000 points, I can say for sure that this is not a dating site.

Comment: Yes.  It has to be a bijection.  if f isn't 1-1 then f(x) = f(y) for some different x and y.  so f({x} $\cap$ {y}) = f($\emptyset$) = $\emptyset$ but $f(\{x\}) \cap f(\{y\}) = \{f(x)\} \cap\{f(y)\} = \{f(x)\}$.  Like $y \in \{x\}^c$ but $f(y) = f(x) \in f(\{x\})$.  So $f(y) \not \in f(\{x\})^c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ($\subseteq$ direction):
   Let $ y \in f(A\cap B)$. Then there exists $x \in A\cap B$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $x \in A$, it follows that $y \in f(A)$ and since $x \in B$, it follows that $y \in f(B)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.

($\supseteq$ direction): Let $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$. Then there exists $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$ with $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y$. But $f$ is injective since it is a bijection. It follows that $x:= x_1 = x_2$, $x \in A \cap B$, and $f(x) = y$ so that $y \in f(A\cap B)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f(A) \cap f(B) \subseteq f(A\cap B)$. $\square$

2. ($\subseteq$ direction): Let $y \in f(A^c) $. Then there exists $x \in A^c$ with $f(x) = y$. Since $f$ is injective, $f$ does not map any other points to $y$ besides $x$. It follows that $y \not \in f(A)$. Hence $y \in f(A)^c$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f(A^c) \subseteq f(A)^c$.

($\supseteq$ direction): Let $y \in f(A)^c$. Then for all $x$ in $A$, $y \not = f(x)$. However, $f$ is surjective since it is a bijection, so there is *some* $x$ in $M$ with $f(x) = y$. This $x$ must be not be in $A$, so $x \in A^c$. Hence $y \in f(A^c)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f(A)^c \subseteq f(A^c)$. $\square$

Comment: Every one gets upvotes

Comment: Intricate argument for the second case

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to show that two sets $U$ and $V$ are equal is to show that $U \subset V$ and $V \subset U$.

For your first equality, let $y \in f(A \cap B)$.  Since $f$ is a bijection, $f^{-1} : N \to M$ is well-defined, and there is a unique $x = f^{-1}(y)$.  By assumption, $x \in A \cap B$. Then since $x \in A$, $y \in f(A)$, and since $x \in B$, $y \in f(B)$.  Thus $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$, and so $f(A \cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Now let $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.  Since $y \in f(A)$, $x \in A$, and since $y \in f(B)$, $x \in B$.  Thus $x \in A \cap B$, so $y = f(x) \in f(A \cap B)$, and so $f(A) \cap f(B) \subset f(A \cap B)$.

You should check the second equality similarly.

Comment: Wow god sent, I would never have thought to use $f^{-1}$, my approach was to say: since $y \in f(A \cap B)$ then $y \in f(A)$ and $f(B)$ so $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$....lol...Actually I have never written a proof like this

Comment: Yeah, you'll get the hang of it.  As Friedrich said in the comments, it's always the same with these kind of exercises (meaning exercises where you have to show that two sets are equal): you want to show both inclusions.  Your approach has the right idea, but you do need to justify the step $y \in f(A \cap B) \Longrightarrow y \in f(A)$ and $f(B)$, even if it seems obvious.